# How to make an android app which talks in source mode(or a simulator like a medical device)

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, health-monitoring

I have a sample android code which talks with medical device using HDP sink profile. I dnt have the actual medical device to test.So is there any easy way to simulate the same using another android project working in source mode and send the sample data.(say pressure monitor).